# Why array of type struct do not work properly?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, operators

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    struct data
    {
        string country;
        string fathername;
        int   age;
    };
        data NAME;

    data name[5]={"Ali", "Usman", "Sarmad", "Awais", "Junaid"};
    name[0]=(struct data){"Saudi Arabia","Tahir Awan",24};
    name[1]=(struct data){"England","Akram Khan",20};
    name[2]=(struct data){"China","Amjad Ali",20};
    name[3]=(struct data){"Syria","Ahmad Ali",19};
    name[4]=(struct data){"Oman","Zohaib Sultan",24};

            cout << "Enter Name of student/n";
            cin >>  NAME;

    int j;
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        if(NAME==name[i])
        j=i;
    }
    cout << "We have following data for   " << name[j]<< endl;
    cout << "Country:  " << name[j].country << endl << "Father name:  " << name[j].fathername << endl << "Age:  " << name[j].age << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

It gives me error in the initialization of array along with lot more errors.I tried a lot to find the reason of errors but could not.Please compile it in your compiler and tell me hw can I remove the errors.Also please tell me the reasons of errors.

Comment: Your initialization of `name` is off.  You subsequent use of C99/C11 'compound literals' is not supported by standard C++, though the `g++` compiler probably does allow it as an extension.  Your use of NAME as though it were a string rather than a structure is not going to work well.  Whole structure comparisons aren't going to work well.  Using an uninitialized `j` is going to lead you into trouble.  And your compiler should be telling you all this.

Comment: In other words, there are too many problems for this question to be useful to any future visitors.

Comment: `data NAME;` --> `struct data NAME;`

Comment: @AmitSharma Unnecessary in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize an element of type `data` by just passing a string, because it also requires another string and an integer. You can use the following instead:

```
data name[5] = {
    {"Saudi Arabia","Tahir Awan",24},
    {"England","Akram Khan",20},
    {"China","Amjad Ali",20},
    {"Syria","Ahmad Ali",19},
    {"Oman","Zohaib Sultan",24}
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13fd1269cd077b34)